# How to calculate the coefficients of a weighted nonlinear regresion model

Tags: regression, weighted-data

I'm trying to build an Excel-sheet that's able to find the a,b and c coefficient of a simple y=ax^2+bx+c model. This is clear enough by [the following math](https://www.voxco.com/blog/quadratic-regression/). But the data I'm using is heteroscedastic, so I'd like to apply some weighting, such as 1/x or 1/(x^2). I can find how to do this for linear regression, but for quadratic/nonlinear regression it's not that straightforward.

Does anyone know a way to do this or a clear reference on how to?

Comment: Nonlinear regression is used for two purposes

To simply fit a smooth curve in order to interpolate values from the curve, or perhaps to draw a graph with a smooth curve. If this is your goal, you can assess it purely by looking at the graph of data and curve. There is no need to learn much theory.

Comment: It seems you have a confusion regarding quadratic equation. It is different from non-linear regression model.